# Copying AWS Snapshots using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, snapshot

I have piece of code for source and destination regions. I managed to have a reponse with all snapshot data but I can't manage to filter the response just to "SnapshotId" and copying it.

```
import boto3

REGIONS = ['eu-central-1', 'eu-west-3']

SOURCEREG = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='eu-central-1')
DISTREG = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='eu-west-3')

response = SOURCEREG.describe_snapshots()
print(response)
```

In this case I receive a json response looking like {'OwnerId': 'xxxxxxx', 'StartTime': datetime.xxxxxxxx, 'SnapshotId': 'snap-xxxxxxxxxx", etc .....}.

How can i filter this output and copy the snapshots?

Comment: Just to understand clearly, you want to copy a snapshot from `eu-central-1` to `eu-west-3` ?

Comment: Yes but i kinda messed up .. and i gave this piece of code. I want for future to be something like for each new snapshot then copy.

Comment: Check out the solution below. looks sufficient for ur problem to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference: [describe_snapshots](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_snapshots) and [copy_snapshot](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.copy_snapshot)

```
import boto3

conn = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='eu-central-1')
response = conn.describe_snapshots()

for snapshots in response['Snapshots']:
    print('Copying Snapshot -> ' + snapshots['SnapshotId'])
    copy_response = conn.copy_snapshot(
        Description='Snapshot copied from' + snapshots['SnapshotId'],
        DestinationRegion='eu-central-1',
        SourceRegion='eu-west-3',
        SourceSnapshotId=snapshots['SnapshotId'],
    )
```