# Is there any boto3 function/API available to copy snapshot from one AWS account to other AWS account?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I have a requirement from my client to copy the EBS snapshots from one AWS account to another AWS account. I am using python and boto3 SDK to implement this.

Comment: ELB snapshots? you mean EBS snapshots, right?

Comment: yes, sorry for the typo

Comment: BTW, I want to copy EBS snapshots from one AWS account to another AWS account i.e., cross-account copying, is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to copy EBS snapshots: check out this answer: [Copying AWS Snapshots using boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51818413/copying-aws-snapshots-using-boto3)

relevant docs: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.copy_snapshot

Comment: BTW, I want to copy EBS snapshots from one AWS account to another AWS account i.e., cross-account copying, is this possible ?

Comment: You can: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-cross-account-copying-of-encrypted-ebs-snapshots/