# Copy AWS Snapshot to S3 bucket using python lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am looking to build a lambda function as part of a forensics workflow that will copy a particular EBS snapshot to a manually created S3 bucket in order to store for short/long term forensics requirements. Looking for any pointers!

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51818413/copying-aws-snapshots-using-boto3) what you are looking for?

Comment: Amazon EBS Snapshots cannot be copied to S3.

Answer (score 1):

The [copy_snapshot](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.copy_snapshot) option is not helpful here. It copies an EBS snapshot to an AWS-controlled S3 bucket (in a different region). It's not to an S3 bucket under your control and you have no direct access to it.

If you genuinely want to export an EBS snapshot to your own S3 bucket, or even to some storage device external to AWS, then you need to do it manually.

One way is as follows (some details are thanks to this [serverfault answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/914362/amazon-aws-export-ebs-snapshot-to-external-storage)):

- launch an EC2 instance
- create an EBS volume from your EBS snapshot
- attach, but do not mount, the EBS volume to your instance
- export the data (to S3 or elsewhere) using a tool such as `dd`

There may be tools available that actually implement this series of steps for you, though I was not able to locate any with a quick search.